# insert custom value to table using grocerycrud Add/Edit

Tags: grocery-crud

I have a table customer with fields id,name,nickname.. I'm using grocery crud for add/edit. The field nickname should be automatically created based upon the name field. Can anyone suggest what can be done to accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using the callback_before_insert function of grocerycrud.

Here is a link to the description: [callback_before_insert](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/callback_before_insert)

Before you render your output add this:

`$crud->callback_before_insert(array($this,'create_nickname_callback'));`

Add the callback method:

```
function create_nickname_callback($post_array) {
$post_array['nickname'] = your_nickname_value;
return $post_array;
```

}